# Iframe dosen't work in npm run build, how can I do?

Tags: webpack, iframe, build

I am using iframe in my project developed react framework.
In the occation of npm run start, iframe works well, but in the npm run build, it doesn't work.

Here are my code.

```
  var sample_url = "https://codesandbox.io/embed/q7jmjyplvq?fontsize=14";

  return (
    <DynamicComponent name="UserProfile.ApiKeyForm" {...props}>
      <Form layout="vertical">
        <hr />
        <Form.Item label="API Key" className="m-b-10">
          <InputWithCopy id={apiKeyInputId} className="hide-in-percy" value={user.apiKey} data-test="ApiKey" readOnly />
        </Form.Item>
        <Button className="w-100" onClick={regenerateApiKey} loading={loading} data-test="RegenerateApiKey">
          Regenerate
        </Button>
      </Form>
      <Button className='w-100' style={{color:'blue', marginTop:'10px'}} onClick={sendKeycloakApi}>API Send</Button>
      <iframe src={sample_url} id="iframeid" title="Plotly All Graph Types" allow="geolocation; microphone; camera; midi; vr; accelerometer; gyroscope; payment; ambient-light-sensor; encrypted-media" sandbox="allow-modals allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
      
    </DynamicComponent>
  );
}
```

In npm run build
[image]

In npm run start

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP869.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-script-loader

https://blog.logrocket.com/best-practices-react-iframes/

https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6967

---

*best practices:*

**You can use the following:**

`(Func:useState() or Class:state:{...})`

**instead of :**

`var simpleurl = '...'`